# Javascripts and Styles loading on every page, one or separated pages?

Tags: jquery, caching, scripting, loading

I searched a while and everyone says different. So I have this question about cache, javascripts files and styles.

Ok let's start, in every tutorial and every site that talking about how to load a files, the correct way to load all my jQuery plugins (I have like 20 scripts for different pages and just few is used on the main page) is in my header or footer and on every page. Even if one of the plugins, let's call it `contact.jquery.js` is not executed on every page (`about.php`, `index.php`) and runs only in `contact.php` and not always reached by the user.

The logic says - if you load all scripts and styles one time from the first page (`index.php`) the loading of the scripts on the second page (`contact.php`) will be cached and will be loaded quickly.

BUT

When I load all scripts from header, my first page is really slow, but when I load 1 script from another page (without putting a script to header) it doesn't take a lot of time to load, because its just one jQuery script.

So here goes no logic, if I seperate scripts on pages where it used, the speed is proportional to pages what user uses.

So what is the best way ?

- To separate scripts by frequency of visits on pages and put scripts on separated pages
- Still load everything from the index page.
- Separate all scripts to different pages and put them to footer.
- Use all scripts in header on the first page but do not let reload some scripts on pages where specific script is used.
- load all plug-ins from header , in all pages , in a single JS file
- use loader like headjs or yepnope

ps: for the styles its the same - contact.css will be loaded from the first page or better from the contact.php. I think for css its better from index, but for scripts im confused.

Comment: maybe [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) a conditional loader for js and css files

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have the below style

**global.css/js**

You can add your common styles/js across the site. Like site logo, header, footer, layout, etc

**Page.css/js**

Add your page specific css/js

**Plugins**

Use minified version of css/js. If possible you can bundle/group and minify based on need

So use common in all pages and add only page specific js/css in the respective page.

However the first request will hit the server and cache the static files like `css/js/img/etc` until you clear the browser cache or a change in url